# How to secure websockets in netty webserver

Tags: java, security, websocket, webserver, netty

I have a webserver in netty with websockets support and I don't know how to secure the websockets, because in the theory anyone can open the websocket and send and receive websocketframes from the websocket.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to add an SSlHandler into your pipeline. Here is an example which will hopefully help you. https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServer.html